# How to make textbox border color fade in on focus using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make the color of the textbox border fade into another color when it is focused? For example if the border color was #ddd then the user focused on the textbox it would fade into #0266C8 and when they unfocus it fades into #ddd again. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Project</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function passwordCheck(y){
    var x = y.value;
    if(x.length>5) {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="Limit is 5 characters";
    } else {
        if(x.length<6) {
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="";
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin:auto;
    font-family:arial, sans-serif;
    padding-top:100px;
}
.container {
    width:920px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.main_text {
    font-family:"Bebas Neue";
    font-size:76px;
    color:green;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.textbox1 {
    border: 4px solid #ddd;
    width: 888px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    font-size: 2em;
    outline: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-radius:100px;
    height:48px;
}
.textbox1:focus {
    border: 4px solid #0266C8;
}
#error {
    font-size:24px;
    color:red;
    font-family:"Bebas Neue";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <span class="main_text">Password Strength Checker</span><br>
    <input name="textbox1" onkeyup="passwordCheck(this);" onKeyPress="passwordCheck(this);" onChange="passwordCheck(this);" onKeyDown="passwordCheck(this);" type="password" class="textbox1" placeholder="Enter Password" style="margin-top:10px;" autofocus><br><br>
    <div id="error"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Omar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS3 transitions.

```
.textbox1 {
    border: 4px solid #ddd;
    width: 888px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    font-size: 2em;
    outline: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-radius:100px;
    height:48px;

     transition: background .5s ease-out; // global
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out; // for mozilla
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-out; // for opera
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out; //for webkit, chrome or safari
}
.textbox1:focus {
    border: 4px solid #0266C8;
     transition: background .5s ease-in; // global
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in; // for mozilla
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in; // for opera
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in; //for webkit, chrome or safari
}
```

You can set the fade delay on `.5s ease-in`

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to fade out when it is unfocused?

Comment: Yes, just put those transitions also to the main element. I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [CSS transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) here:

```
transition: border-color 1s linear;
-moz-transition: border-color 1s linear;   
-o-transition: border-color 1s linear; 
-webkit-transition: border-color 1s linear;
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AvT27/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
.container input{
 -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
 -o-transition: all 1s linear;
 transition: all 1s linear;
}

.container input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #4F94CD;
}
```